# How to find nouns and singularize using nlp-compromise

Tags: javascript, nlp, nlp-compromise

For example, if I have `"hearts attack"`, I'd like to first find noun `"hearts"`, and then convert to `"heart"`, but still keep `"heart attack"`

How can I do this in NLP-compromise?

I've tried

```
doc.match("#Noun").nouns().toSingular().out('text')
```

or

```
doc.nouns().toSingular().out('text')
```

This will simply generate `"heart"` but lose `"attack"`

Answer (score 0):

Just get it work.

Simply try:

```
doc.nouns().toSingular()
var input2 = doc.out('text')
```

But it puzzled me, what's the difference?

Comment: hey Ciro, `.nouns()` grabs just the nouns in the document. if you want the whole doc, you can call `.all()`, or just refer to `doc` again, like you figured-out
https://runkit.com/spencermountain/5977e94fce6a1b001269b643

Comment: @sepencercooly I tried with `var doc=nlp("not serve as")
doc.nouns().toSingular().out() > ""` which is correct (no nouns in the sentence) but `var doc=nlp("not serve as")
doc.nouns().toSingular().out()  > "not serve as"` and return the sentence without filtering nouns.

Aslo : `var doc=nlp("backbone that encodes")
doc.nouns().toSingular().out()  > "backbone"` (correct) `var doc=nlp("backbone that encodes")
doc.nouns().toSingular().all().out()
"backbone that encodes"` (I d expect backbone again)